# Problems between IIS and OPC Server

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, opc

I am developing an application in ASP that use a connection with a OPC Server. I have tested my program with Web Developer IDE and my application successfully connects and reads data from the OPC Server.

But when I passed my project to IIS, I have a problem, the application does not connect to the OPC server. My OPC Server is located in opcda://localhost/Matrikon.OPC.Simulation.1 and the application in the IIS is located in localhost:85/Vista/andon.aspx and I don't know what happened.

I use a OPC Foundation libraries.

Comment: How is IIS configured in terms of user accounts running your app? Check the Application Pool to which your app is assigned, and its identity. Then, make sure this user has all the permissions to hit the OPC server. In order to check whether this is the actual issue, set the identity (temporarily - a security issue!) to an account you know that works (e.g. your own account), and re-test.

Comment: ZbynekZ thank you for your reply. I tried this and added the permissions to the OPC server in special in the DCOM. But I have a mysterious problem when I subscribed one item the program works fine and when subscribes more than one item the program crash and I get this excepcion  Opc.ResultIDException: E_FAIL IOPCItemMgt.AddItems. This is rare because this is the same code that use in my Web Developer IDE and the Web Developer IDE works properly with a lot items, but in the IIS doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure this is related to IIS. I have seen the same issue with a Windows Service.